# When $\gcd{(ug, vg)}=g$, we have $\gcd{(ug, vg+1)}=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, divisibility

I have a question about greatest common divisor.

For an **even** integer $g$, assume that $\gcd{(ug, vg)}=g$, i.e., $\gcd{(u, v)}=1$.

Then we have $\gcd{(ug, vg+1)}=1$?

For example, let $g=2$, $u=8$, and $v=7$. Then $\gcd{(ug, vg)}=\gcd{(16, 14)}=2=g$.

Plus, $\gcd{(ug, vg+1)}=\gcd{(16, 15)}=1$. This is generally true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try other numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

Let consider $u=7$, $v=3$ and $g=2$.

$GCD(14,6)=2$ and $GCD(7,3)=1$ but $GCD(14,7)=7$.

Answer (score 0):

Not true in general: $\gcd(5,6)=1$ and $\gcd(4\cdot5,4\cdot 6 +1)=\gcd(20,25)=5$.

Note that $g=4$, hence it fails for some even $g$.

Maybe you want to restrict $u,v$ to be primes? Or put some other restrictions on your variables. Try it, and see what you can do.